# Processing perl CGI on external server from web server

Tags: iis, perl

I have a web server (IIS) running perl.  Is there any way to offload the perl processing to an external server?  For example, I have server_a with various sites that may include perl CGI scripts.  I want to have server_b such that when requests for a perl script are issued to server_a, the processing is offloaded to server_b.

Adobe ColdFusion server has such capabilities with their Web Connector.  Anyone know of such a thing for perl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what Chris S mentioned, you might consider this if the perl is triggered by an external http hit

```
- Assume the hostname for the existing IIS perl server is `www.foobarme.local`.

- Assume the hostname for the new perl offload server is `perl.foobarme.local` 
(you probably already know where I'm going at this point)

- Rewrite your HTML to refer to `perl.foobarme.local`.
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily setup server A to proxy certain requests to server B where the perl processing takes place. You could get into more complicated schemes, but I doubt they'd work well in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a page that explains how to setup the reverse proxying and URL rewriting correctly so that it actually works:

http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx